# Apache 2.4 Rewrite URL matching full URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache 2.4 as Reverse Proxy, and I need to redirect to an URL, only if credential is passed into URL. For Example, this is my URL:

https://user:password@myserver.mydomain.com/site1.php?1

I use this Rewrite Condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^user:password@ohab\.marcolino7\.myds\.me$
```

But it do not match, i suppose because HTTP_HOST do not contain authentication data.
In there a way to match the URL with also authentication data and then so I can redirect?

Many Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly say, that is not part of the host header, so wouldn't match like that.

You can do it using the `REMOTE_USER` variable. How you do it depends on the context of your rules. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and specifically the quote below.

> `%{LA-U:variable}` can be used for look-aheads which perform an
>   internal (URL-based) sub-request to determine the final value of
>   *variable*. This can be used to access variable for rewriting which is
>   not available at the current stage, but will be set in a later phase.
>
> For instance, to rewrite according to the `REMOTE_USER` variable from
>   within the per-server context (`httpd.conf` file) you must use
>   `%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}` - this variable is set by the authorization
>   phases, which come *after* the URL translation phase (during which
>   mod_rewrite operates).
>
> On the other hand, because mod_rewrite implements its per-directory
>   context (`.htaccess` file) via the Fixup phase of the API and because
>   the authorization phases come before this phase, you just can use
>   `%{REMOTE_USER}` in that context.

Something like this in your `httpd.conf` file:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} =user
```

Or in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =user
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, but it is not my case. I need to rewrite only one time, when the URL is passed with username and password, and not when url is just rewrited.